# Angular2 Object Undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

Getting "object undefined" while accessing object of Service Component. But hard coded below data to javaScript variable working fine and shows object type "object Array"

Data.json

```
[
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Malad",
        "gateway": "10.10.100.1",
        "device": "cisco"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kandhivali",
        "gateway": "222.30.100.1",
        "device": "Juniper"
      }
]
```

DataService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  tdata = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Malad",
    "gateway": "10.10.100.1",
    "device": "cisco"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Kandhivali",
    "gateway": "222.30.100.1",
    "device": "Juniper"
  }
];

  data;
  constructor(http: Http){
    http.get('Data.json')
    .toRx()
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => this.data= res);
  }

}
```

DataPage.ts

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {DataService} from './DataService'

@Component({
  selector: 'DataPage'
})
@View({
  template: `
{{data | json}}  //Working //object Array
<br>
{{data | json}}  //Not Wokring // object Undefined //No data :(
`


directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class DataPage{
  query;
  tquery;
    constructor( public dataService:DataService){

       this.query = dataService.data; // object Undefined
       this.tquery = dataService.tdata; //object Array

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are getting `data` asynchronously. You can't expect the service to return the value when you call it, so you should return the Observable in your service and subscribe to it in your component.

In your service

```js
constructor(http: Http){
    this.http = http;
}
myData() {
  return this.http.get('Data.json')
     .toRx()
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

In your component

```js
constructor( public dataService:DataService){

       dataService.myData().subscribe(res => this.query = res);

       this.tquery = dataService.tdata; //object Array
  }
```

and change your view to this

```js
@View({
    template: `
     {{tquery| json}}
     <br>
     {{query | json}}
    `
```

Here's a repro : http://plnkr.co/edit/BeMpYR?p=preview